# Some clarity on LINQ/LAMBDA to retrieve data from an intersection table please?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have the following entities:

```
Order -< OrderItem >- Product
```

I need to write some LINQ that will retrieve all order that contains Order Items with Product with Id = 100.

So I started along the line of:

```
var Order = Order.Where(r=>r.OrderItems.ProductId == 100) ???
```

Help with the required LINQ would be hugely appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = Orders.Where(o => o.OrderItems.Any(oi => oi.ProductId == 100));
```

Comment: Thanks. THought it was a simple one.